# combine output of pipes

Tags: bash, pipe

Let's say I run a command in Bash like:

```
ls  -l | grep filename
```

How can I save output of both command to a variable? In another words output of "ls  -l" and "grep filename" to the same variable?
The command must use a pipe.

Thank you in advance!

```
combinedOutput = ""

ls -l
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 webmaster webmaster 0 Nov 16 20:34 a
-rw-r--r-- 1 webmaster webmaster 0 Nov 16 20:34 b
-rw-r--r-- 1 webmaster webmaster 0 Nov 16 20:34 file1.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 webmaster webmaster 0 Nov 16 20:34 file2.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 webmaster webmaster 5 Nov 16 20:34 main.sh

ls  -l | grep main.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 webmaster webmaster 20 Nov 16 20:35 main.sh


echo  $combinedOutput 
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 webmaster webmaster 0 Nov 16 20:34 a
-rw-r--r-- 1 webmaster webmaster 0 Nov 16 20:34 b
-rw-r--r-- 1 webmaster webmaster 0 Nov 16 20:34 file1.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 webmaster webmaster 0 Nov 16 20:34 file2.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 webmaster webmaster 5 Nov 16 20:34 main.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 webmaster webmaster 20 Nov 16 20:35 main.sh
```

**UPDATE #1:**
A  better example: let's say I am  trying to archive and  compress a directory using the following command:

```
tar  cvf - /some/directory/ |  pigz --verbose -1 -p 4 >compressed_archive.tgz;
```

The question is how to put outputs of "tar  cvf - /some/directory/"  and "pigz --verbose -1 -p 4 >compressed_archive.tgz" to a variable.

Comment: Are you asking for `variable=$(command1 | command2)`? Please explain "the same variable".

Comment: I don't understand how you are getting two different listings for `main.sh`; `ls -l` shows `5 Nov 16 20:34` and `ls -l | grep main.sh` shows `20 Nov 16 20:35`; it appears you've run the two commands at two different times (with some sort of modification of `main.sh` occurring in between) ... and if that's the case then just store each call in a different variable (eg, `var1=$(ls -l)` / `var2=$(ls -l | grep main.sh)`)

Comment: If you want the output of `ls` for one file, just pass the filename as an argument. If you want it for a bunch of files that match some pattern, use somethigng like `find . -name '*filename*' -exec ls {} +`. *Don't* try to use `grep` on the full output of `ls`.

Comment: `combinedOutput=$(ls -l); combinedOutput+=$'\n'"$(grep main.sh <<<"$combinedOutput")"` -- though I don't know _why_ anyone would ever do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply:

```bash
combinedOutput=$(( ls -l | tee /dev/stderr | grep filename ) 2>&1)
echo "$combinedOutput"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just run two commands.

```
combinedOutput=$(
   ls -l
   ls -l | grep filename
)
```

But anyway, you may be more comfortable with just:

```
one=$(ls -l)
two=$(ls -l | grep filename)
combinedOutput="$one
$two"
```

It's not possible to get the output you want with `echo  $combinedOutput`. You can do `echo "$combinedOutput"`. Consider researching shell quoting. Check your scripts with shellcheck.

Comment: let's say  it is not "ls -l" but a command which does  something like  "tar  cvf .. ". Thus,  spliting to two commands  is  not an option.

Comment: I do not understand. So `one=$(tar cvs); two="$one $(grep filename <<<"$one")"`. Really, sky the limit.